# Cannot mark a message as read while using mailboxer in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mailboxer

How can I mark any message as read in [mailboxer](https://github.com/ging/mailboxer)?

Even if I add the line: `<% conversation.mark_as_read(current_user) %>` in my view, it does not solve my problem.

Comment: Could you please describe the issue in more detail?? like: where you're trying to add `<% conversation.mark_as_read(current_user) %>` and what view/controller/model etc?

Comment: i m trying to understand how sample app (https://github.com/RKushnir/mailboxer-app) uses mailboxer. I added <% conversation.mark_as_read(current_user) %>  in show page of conversations controller. My major problem is how can i set the read attribute of a receipt when a user has seen the message in his inbox.If i set read=true manually,i get an :read only attribute" error.I want unread count basically .

Comment: It works now.Not sure what the problem was but anyways it works with the same line conversation.mark_as_read(current_user) but this code should be added in view and not the controller because it only belongs to the views and not the controllers.

Comment: I was going through this: https://github.com/frodefi/rails-messaging to see if anything is related. however I didn't find any code which line: `<% conversation.mark_as_read(current_user) %> ` in the sample app's github link you posted. Anyway, I am glad that your issue is resolved.

Comment: Thanks but the link was https://github.com/RKushnir/mailboxer-app and you have to add this line <% conversation.mark_as_read(current_user) %> manually to mark a conversation as read in show page of conversations controller because if u dont,all the messages will be marked unread even after a user views all those messages.Not sure why they did not add it themselves on github.But when i added this,the app worked fine and i am now able to get the unread message count.

Comment: I checked https://github.com/RKushnir/mailboxer-app repository for the mentioned method. link github.com/frodefi/rails-messaging was something related so I thought it might have what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anybody else has this issue in the future, the solution is to only put code like what is in the original question in something like `MessagesController`, and to create a form which points to that action.